# Check if dictionary contains at least one specific value out of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What's the most elegant way to check if at least one specific value exists within a dictionary out of a list of 'targets'? I've been using or statements in the past, but these can be fairly lengthy:

```
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}

if 'six' in d.values() or 'eight' in d.values() or 'ten' in d.values() or 'fifteen' in d.values():
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Is it better to create a list of targets, then loop through that list to check each against the dictionary individually? In that case, I'd also need to put breaks at the end of the if/else blocks to ensure it's not triggered multiple times:

```
targets = ['six', 'eight', 'ten', 'fifteen']
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}

for t in targets:
    if t in d.values():
        # do something
        break  # to ensure the thing isn't triggered multiple times
    else:
        # do something else
        break  # to ensure the thing isn't triggered multiple times
```

Is there a recommended way to shorten this, or is the 2nd code block as good as it gets?

Comment: ```if [i for i in targets if i in d.values()]:``` Maybe not the most glamorous, but it does shorten your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace it with the next one:

```
if any(t in d.values() for t in targets):
    pass
else:
    pass
```

In some cases will be better to convert `d.values()` into set and pass to the additional variable.

```
values = set(d.values())

if any(t in values for t in targets):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert dictionary values and the list of targets to [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), and do operations on sets, in this case, intersection:

```
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}
targets = ['four', 'nine']

if set(d.values()) & set(targets):
    print('overlap')
else:
    print('no overlap')
```

Comment: The OP asked for an elegant solution. Your solution should have been up voted too .. Rectifying the situation by 1.

Answer (score 1):

It will be faster to use a set's isdisjoint() method than intersecting two sets because you won't need to form a resulting set and the method will return False on the first intersecting value:

```
if {"six","eight","ten","fifteen"}.isdisjoint(d.values()):
    print("None of the values are present")
else:
    print("At least one of the values is present")
```